# Challenges trying to create an approval form with deep link in PowerApps. Error: "Incompatible types for comparison. Record: Text"

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate, power-platform

I'm trying to build a business issue tracker app in PowerApps.

Requirement: Once an issue is raised the Line Manager the user selected, reviews the form ( makes comments on 2 specific fields - 'Priority' and 'Additional comments').

**App Details**
Datasource : 'Business Tracker'(Sharepoint List)
Line manager: A column on the sharepoint list ( Type: People)

My challenge is trying to create this in the Power Apps and Power Automate. Using some references online i saw i could use this code on the  APP start Screen:

If(!IsBlank(Param("ID")) && LookUp('Business Tracker', ID = Value(Param("ID"))).'Line Manager'= User().Email, Newform_1, MainScreen).

But when i do i get an error:

"Incompatible types for comparison. These types can't be compared, Record: Text"

In power automate flow i set a Parameter ID.

**In Power Apps, the On Start code:
**
If(
!IsBlank(Param("ID")),
Set(
VarItem,
LookUp(
'Business Tracker',
ID = Value(Param("ID"))
)
);
Set(
varFormMode,
FormMode.Edit
)
)

```
**In Power Apps, the Start Screen code: ** 

If(!IsBlank(Param("ID")) && LookUp('Business Tracker', ID = Value(Param("ID"))).'Line Manager'= User().Email, Newform_1, MainScreen)

My Expectation: 

Once a new business issue is created, the line manager that was selected, will receive an email with a link to review and make comments on the 'priority' and 'comments' field...This should only apply if the user is the line manager, otherwise default to the home screen.
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like LookUp('Business Tracker', ID = Value(Param("ID"))).'Line Manager' is returning a record and you are compariing it to User().Email which is text. Your 'line manager' value will be a record because it is a people type column, it holds multiple values. you need .Email to select the email address from the Line Manager record. Like so:

```html
If(!IsBlank(Param("ID")) && LookUp('Business Tracker', ID = Value(Param("ID"))).'Line Manager'.Email= User().Email, Newform_1, MainScreen).
```